# Best way to organize this logic?

Tags: function, optimization, logic

I have a function with two parameters A and B which can both be null or not. I am looking for the most concise way of writing this function. The following is the rules for it.

> - case A == null, B == null : do nothing
> - case A == null, B != null : create new instance of A and call A.doStuff(B)
> - case A != null, B != null : call A.doStuff(B)
> - case A != null, B == null : call A.dostuff(B)

This is what I have come up with:

```
 public void myFunction( MyObject A, MyObject b )
    {
        if (A == null)
        {
            if (B != null)
            {
                A = new A();
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        A.doStuff( B );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think it is a matter of your personal preference. Honestly, I would write it like this:

```
 public void myFunction( MyObject A, MyObject b ) {
    if (A == null && B == null) return;
    if (A == null) A = new A();
    A.doStuff(b);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void myFunction( MyObject A, MyObject b ) {
    if (A){
       A.doStuff(b);
    }else if (B){
      A = new A();
      A.doStuff(b)
    }
 }
```

This would be how I would write it